# Override the zoom behaviour of QgsMapToolExtent

Tags: pyqgis, qgsmapcanvas

###### Context

The default behaviour of the [QgsMapToolExtent](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/gui/QgsMapToolExtent.html) is to draw an extent (using [QgsRubberBand](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/gui/QgsRubberBand.html)) on the map canvas while the left mouse button is held and emit that extent when it is released.

Holding the Shift key implements a modified behaviour where the `QgsRubberBand` has an altered appearance (blue instead of grey) and the cursor changes to a magnifying glass. On releasing the left mouse button in this case, the map is zoomed to the drawn extent.

###### Aim

I want to block the zooming behaviour of `QgsMapToolExtent` and use the `Qt.ShiftModifier` for another purpose.

###### Unsuccessful attempts

I have subclassed `QgsMapToolExtent` and tried overriding the `canvasPress`, `canvasRelease`, and `canvasMove` events (modified with the the `Qt.ShiftModifier`) but to no avail. The zooming behaviour is being initiated somewhere else.

```py
class MyMapTool(QgsMapToolExtent):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        super().__init__(canvas)
        
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.extentChanged.connect(self.myFunc)
            
    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier:
            print("Canvas press event and Shift key held") # no effect
        else:
            super().canvasPressEvent(event)
            
    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier:
            print("Canvas release event and Shift key held") # works intermittently / only for double-click (does not override zooming behaviour)
        else:
            super().canvasReleaseEvent(event)
            
    def canvasMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier:
            print("Canvas move event while Shift key held") # works but does not override zooming behaviour
        else:
            super().canvasMoveEvent(event)
       
    def myFunc(self, rect):
        self.clearRubberBand()
        
    def setTool(self):
        self.canvas.setMapTool(self)
        
    def unsetTool(self):
        self.canvas.unsetMapTool(self)
        
myMapTool = MyMapTool(iface.mapCanvas())
myMapTool.setTool()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour where the `QgsRubberBand` has a different appearance and the cursor changes to a magnifying glass is not specific to `QgsMapToolExtent`.

It is rather a function of the map canvas (implemented in `QgsMapCanvas::beginZoomRect`) and called on each mouse press event the canvas receives.
If the shift key is pressed the canvas consumes the event, draws the rubber band and doesn't forward it to the active map tool. Therefore your your `canvasPressEvent` doesn't have the desired effect.

To disable this feature you can can modify the flags returned by the map tool to not include `QgsMapTool.AllowZoomRect` (see [`QgsMapTool::Flag`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html#acc97c82d572ee6523047b9df32f783b7)) by adding the following function to your map tool implementation:

```
def flags(self):
    return super().flags() & ~QgsMapTool.AllowZoomRect
```